# Incorrect UNC path when doing gastby serve

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am getting below error when doing gatsby serve as my office is using proxy and it will not paths like this one given below.

**Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, copyfile 'C:\gatsby\static.gitkeep' -> 'C:\gatsby\public.gitkeep'**

When i check the app which is stopping the file copy, in it's logger i see URL it starts with **\\?**

**\\?C:\\FILE URL**

Can anyone please guide what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a hidden file inside the `/static` folder named `.gitkeep`. The static folder is transpiled into the public one using its internal structure when you build and serve the project and it's failing because it's not a valid type file.

To solve the issue just remove the `.gitkeep` file.

Comment: I removed the file .gitkeep. It is working. Thank a lot Ferran.